# Extract domain from URL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have data like this:

```
**User  URL**
1   http://www.groupon.com/
1   http://www.groupon.com/
1   http://www.groupon.com/
2   http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page
2   http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page
3   http://www.google.com/imghp
3   http://www.google.com/imghp
```

I want to extract their domains into another column, like this:

```
**User  URL                             Domain**
1   http://www.groupon.com/             groupon.com
1   http://www.groupon.com/today        groupon.com
1   http://www.groupon.com/deals        groupon.com
2   http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page    wikihow.com
2   http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page    wikihow.com
3   http://www.google.com/imghp         google.com/imghp
3   http://www.google.com/flights           google.com
```

Not sure how to do this as a beginner. My intuition is that I need to extract everything between '://' and the next '/'.

I think I want to start like, this but not sure how to get the length for the third SUBSTR argument (I know the length I want is the location of the third '/' MINUS the location of the second '/'):

```
SUBSTR(URL, INDEX(URL, "://)+7, ???)
```

Added bonus: For a very specific case (google.com/imghp), I want the domain column to show google.com/imghp instead of just the domain.

If you can help with the code for this exception as well, that would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you have domains with more than 3 parts? Like `www.company.com.uk`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the third parameter of the SUBSTR with a nested CHARINDEX.  CHARINDEX has an optional 3rd parameter that lets you specify the starting position to begin searching from.  It's going to be a long ugly query, but it will get the string you are looking for.

SUBSTR(URL, CHARINDEX(URL, [StartingPoint]), (CHARINDEX(URL, [EndingPoint], (CHARINDEX(URL, [StartingPoint])))-CHARINDEX(URL, [StartingPoint])))

As for the "special case", you can handle that with a LIKE '%google.com/imghp%' in a CASE statement.

What really concerns me is that there could be a lot of URL formats that break your rule for getting the domain that you aren't accounting for.   What about:

www.SomeDepartment.SomeCompany.com

www.SomeCompany.com.CountryCode

www2.SomeCompany.com

And have you seen some of the .edu URLS with 5+ elements?   I would ask the consumer of this information for a clear business rule about what exactly constitutes the "domain" in any possible URL format.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer but it does the trick. You can improve on my code. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bc71/11) I created. Hope it makes sense

```
CREATE TABLE myurls 
    (
     user int, 
     url varchar(40), 
     domain varchar(40)
    );

INSERT INTO myurls
(user, url)
VALUES
('1', 'http://www.groupon.com'),
('1', 'http://www.groupon.com'),
('2', 'http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page'),
('2', 'http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page');


SELECT user, url, SUBSTRING(url, 11, 100) AS domains
FROM myurls;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created your test cases and a few extras that I thought of as I was developing my answer:-

```
set nocount on
go
create table #log (
    url varchar(50)
)
go
insert into #log values('http://www.groupon.com/')
insert into #log values('http://www.groupon.com/today')
insert into #log values('https://groupon.com/deals')
insert into #log values('http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page')
insert into #log values('http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page')
insert into #log values('https://www.google.com/imghp')
insert into #log values('http://google.com/flights')
insert into #log values('http://www.amazon.com/cameras')
insert into #log values('https://www.amazon.co.uk/cameras')
go
```

and then created this function:-

```
create function dbo.GetDomain(@url varchar(1024)) 
returns varchar(1024) as begin
    declare @returnValue varchar(1024)
    declare @position int
    declare @pattern varchar(50)
    if CHARINDEX('google.com/imghp',@url)>0 --if it's your special case
        set @returnValue='google.com/imghp'
    else begin
        set @url=replace(@url,'http://','') --strip off typical prefixes
        set @url=replace(@url,'https://','')
        set @position=CHARINDEX('/',@url) --check if there is a slash
        if @position>0
            set @url=left(@url,@position-1) --and strip it and everything after it off
        select @pattern=case
            when PATINDEX('%.co.uk',@url)>0 then '%.%.%.%' --repeat this line for any other exceptions
            else '%.%.%'
        end
        while PATINDEX(@pattern,@url)>0 begin --now check if our pattern matches
            set @url=SUBSTRING(@url,CHARINDEX('.',@url)+1,1024) --and strip off the prefix if it does
        end
        set @returnValue=@url
    end
    return @ReturnValue
end
go
```

which when called:-

```
select *, dbo.GetDomain(url) as domain
from #log
go
```

produces:-

```
url                               domain
http://www.groupon.com/           groupon.com
http://www.groupon.com/today      groupon.com
https://groupon.com/deals         groupon.com
http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page  wikihow.com
http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page  wikihow.com
https://www.google.com/imghp      google.com/imghp
http://google.com/flights         google.com
http://www.amazon.com/cameras     amazon.com
https://www.amazon.co.uk/cameras  amazon.co.uk
```